# I need to prove that $f$ continuous at $(x)=0$ using a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I need to prove that $f$  continuous at $(x)=0$ using a $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof
$$
  f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
x^2sin(\frac1x),&x\neq 0
\\
0,&x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: it also possesses a first derivative everywhere. The derivative, however, is discontinuous at $0.$ Go figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $0<|x|<\delta$ then $$|f(x)-f(0)| = |x^2 \sin(1/x)|\le|x|^2 < \delta^2$$
Thus we for every $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ such that...

Comment: Be sure you check out the edits I made, and note why each of them--save changing $x^2$ to $|x|^2$--was essential for the proof.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: For $x\neq 0$, $$|f(x)-f(0)|=\left|x^2\cdot\sin\frac1x-0\right|=|x|^2\left|\sin\frac1x\right|\leq|x|^2=|x-0|^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

This post is only meant to be a supplement to the answers posted above.(So that the process is understood.)

You have to prove that the limit of the function as x tends to zero is the same as the value of the function at zero.

Here epsilon is the upper bound on the distance between an abitrary f(x) and and f(0). And delta is the upper bound on the distance between an arbitrary x and 0. If you can prove that you can bring f(x) as close to f(0) as you wish, by bringing x as near to zero, you prove that the limit of the function as x tends to zero exists.(This can be done without the epsilon - delta definition, by using algebraic manipulation, but it won't be rigorous.More rigorously, for any arbitrary epsilon, you should be able to find a delta - and for this you have to use the epsilon-delta definition.)

Note that epsilon and delta are both greater than zero, so this excludes the case f(x) = f(0) and the case x = 0. So it only proves that the limit exists, it says nothing about the behaviour of the function at x= 0. So you have to prove that the limit above is equal to the value of f(x) at x = 0. Here since it is already given that f(0) = 0, all you have to do is to state the fact.(A practically trivial, but logically important step).

Comment: As an addition, as to how the above limit could be solved, without the epsilon - delta definition, note that sin(1/x) is bounded(its absoute value never exceeds unity), so the limit of this function as x tends to zero is zero.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. Can you explain?

Comment: I am busy with something else now, so may not be able to respond immediately, but do post your answer.

Comment: We don't really need to exclude equality in either case. Suppose we're trying to do an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the continuity of a function $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ at $x=a$. Think of $\epsilon$ as the length of a chain attached to $g(x)$ and $g(a)$; $\delta$ to $x$ and $a$, where we want to make the $\delta$-chain short enough that $g(x)$ doesn't hurt itself when $x$ runs around. We will still let $x$ and $g(x)$ run around a bit, and they can even come right up to the base of the chain, *i.e.*: $g(x)=g(a)$ or $x=a$.

Comment: Of course, it isn't very interesting to let $x=a$, because then we'll necessarily have $g(x)=g(a)$. Hence, some texts require $x\neq a$. In some cases, though, that restriction won't be enough to avoid situations with $g(x)=g(a)$. For example, consider $f(x)$ from this post, and say we take $\epsilon=1$. Then taking $\delta=1$, we know for any $0<|x|<\delta$ that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$. However, there are infinitely-many such $x$ with $|f(x)-f(0)|=0$, namely $x=\frac{1}{k\pi}$ for non-zero integers $k$, and these $x$ get arbitrarily close to (but not equal to) $0$.

Comment: So, even if we don't want to allow $x=a$ in our $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, we *have* to allow the possibility that $g(x)=g(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the example. Clear explanation.

Comment: But one thing, the reason that x = 0 is not included in the definition...couldn't it be for the fact that g(x), need not be defined at x = a? I mean generally the epsilon delta definition is used to prove that a function has an already given limit(not to evaluate it.). So, if you have a function that's already defined at x = a, then naturally it doesn't make sense to include x = a(because as you said, necessarily, g(x) = g(a)).But if the function is not defined at a, then we would have have to compare its behaviour at x = a, wouldn't we?

Comment: My point is that just as we can use the epsilon- delta function as a proof writing tool with continuous functions, we can also use it as a proof writing tool with non-continuous functions. Can't we?

Comment: I am now thinking, about your sentence 'that restriction won't be enough to avoid situations with g(x) = g(a)' - a similar situation occurs in the rigorous proof of the chain rule in differentiation, when for a non- zero change in the independent variable , the change in the inner function could be zero. I was looking for an example, here I found it. Thanks once again! But do reply on my earlier post.

Comment: If all we want to show is that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=L$ for some real $L$, then we certainly must require that $x\neq a$, for as you say, $g$ needn't be defined at $a$, or (even if it is defined) we may have $g(a)\neq L$ in the case that $g$ has a removable discontinuity at $a$. You're quite right about that. However, if we're trying to prove that the function $g$ is continuous at $a$, then neither of these will be concerns. (P.S.: Always glad to accidentally answer another question.)

Comment: Thanks, your explanations are very clear.

Comment: Just to make sure, that I understood ' removable discontinuity' , correctly, the function in the OP has a removable discontinuity at x = 0, right? Then we must require g(x) not equal to 0, shouldn't we? And what about x?

Comment: Again, something's come up, so I'll be late in replying. But do post your answer.

Comment: Not quite (if I understand you correctly)--in fact it is continuous at $x=0$, which is what is to be proved. If we'd defined $f(0)$ to be something *other* than $0$, then *would* have a removable discontinuity. Such a discontinuity happens when both $g(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ are defined, but are *not* equal to each other.

Comment: Let's say we defined $h(x)=x^2\sin\frac1x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $h(0)=2$. To show that $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$ via $\epsilon$-$\delta$ approach, we must show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x)-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-0|<\delta$. Here, we **have** to have $x\neq 0$ (since we'll fail otherwise), but really, we're only interested in the behavior of $h$ *near* $x=0$, so we really don't care what happens when $x=0$. Again, for the same reason as before, we *can't* require that $h(x)\neq 0$. For a clearer example, take a function that's constant, except at one point.

Comment: Ok, what if in the OP, he'd made no mention of the behaviour at x= 0? ie., if he'd simply said, f(x) = x^2 sin (1/x). Then it would have a removable discontinuity, right? .(I've seen a similar approach in Advanced Calculus by Angus Taylor, where he makes no mention of the behaviour of the same function at x = 0, then goes on to say that, if we let f(0) = limit of f(x), as x tends to zero, then, it would be continuous at x = 0. He doesn't use the phrase 'removable disontinuity' though).

Comment: If no mention had been made of $x=0$, then the function wouldn't be defined at $x=0$, so would be *neither* continuous *nor* discontinuous there. Indeed, the *limit* of the function would exist there, but the function, itself, would not.

Comment: 'Nor discontinuous' - that's interesting.... Is there a name(technical term) for such behaviour?

Comment: It isn't really a kind of behavior. It's simply that the function wouldn't be defined there, and we can talk about *any* of a function's characteristics in a place where it isn't defined.

Comment: In the post above did you mean 'we can' or 'we can't'?

Comment: Apologies. That was supposed to be "we can't".

Comment: Ok, thank you. This was a very fruitful discussion. I learnt a lot of things regarding the epsilon-delta definition. As an aside, I find your, explanations using the epsilon-delta definition very insightful as well as intuitive. So I was hoping, if you could help me with a question, I posted on this site, a couple of days ago,(308839) titled - 'Limit Question Explanation'. Its regarding the intuitive explanation of three limits.